# Is it more secure, if a single page application has its own server

Tags: asp.net, security, single-page-application, static-files

I have a single page application (angular 2+), deployed as static files of my .Net core backend.

There are people who claim: It would be more secure, if the frontend part of the application would have its own server.

but I cannot find any reasons on the Internet why it should be more secure.

Does anyone know if is there really a difference as far as the security is concerned?

Comment: What kind of "secure" are you looking for? Secure for your users? Secure for your infrastructure? What kind of threat model?

Comment: @UweKeim i'm looking for every kind of secure for my users but mainly for my infrastructure. The question is in general is it better to deploy the frontend on a separat server?

Comment: Having the frontend separated from the backend will at least allow you to scale them individually. But with every new component (server) your attack surface gets bigger.

Comment: @ibexit can you explain you last sentence "with every new component (server) your attack surface gets bigger" better? Where can I find more information about it?

Comment: More systems, more maintenance, more potential vulnerabilites. On the other side, if you combine services on single host, you'll increase the vulnerabilites too, as the complexity of the system increases.

Comment: Can you post a link with an example of someone saying frontend-only server would be more secure? If not, where did you hear that?